# Adding child to borderpane center resizes button in top

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I'm currently migrating a JavaFx app to TornadoFx. I would like to add a chart on button click. I ended up with the following, stripped-down code:

```
borderpane {
    prefWidth = 1000.0
    prefHeight = 750.0
    padding = insets(10)
    top = vbox {
        spacing = 5.0
        hbox {
            spacing = 5.0
            alignment = Pos.CENTER_LEFT
            button("Show") {
                action {

                    val centerRef = this@borderpane.center as VBox
                    println(centerRef.id)

                    if (centerRef.children.size  > 0)
                        centerRef.children.removeAll(centerRef.children)

                    val seriesData = (1..25)
                            .map { Random().nextDouble() }
                            .zip((1..25).map { Random().nextDouble() })
                            .toMap()

                    centerRef.add(linechart("My Chart", NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()) {
                        series("my series") {
                            for ((k,v) in seriesData) {
                                data(k, v)
                            }
                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        }
        separator()
    }
    center = vbox { id = "centervbox" }
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as the event gets fired, the button is resized. I tried to set the buttons max width and height, but the settings are ignored. I'm new to Kotlin and TornadoFx (some experience with JavaFx, though) and really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Edit: I get the same weird behavior with this code, that is, the first chart is placed within the button. Only after the second click the chart is added to the VBox correctly.

```
vbox {
    prefWidth = 1000.0
    prefHeight = 750.0
    id = "rootvbox"
    button("button1") {
        action {
            val vbRef = this@vbox
            println(vbRef.id)
            val lc = linechart("My Chart", NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()) {
                series("my series") {
                    for ((k,v) in (1..25).map { Random().nextDouble() }.zip((1..25).map { Random().nextDouble() }).toMap()) {
                        data(k, v)
                    }
                }
            }
            vbRef.children.add(lc)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally adding the linechart to your button. It's extremely important to understand how the builders work - if you call a builder function, for example `linechart()` on a node, the new component will be added to that node. So here you're doing:

```
button("Show") {
    action {
         centerRef.add(linechart(...))
    }
}
```

This is telling the framework to create a linechart inside of the button, and then adding it to centerRef. You're actually calling `this@button.linechart()`. The builders job is not just to build the element, but also attaching it to it's parent. So you can fix your issue simply by calling `centerRef.linechart(..)` instead.

You should try to avoid relying on other UI elements and keep as few references between components as possible. The following example uses events to reduce coupling:

```
// An event containing a builder that will construct the chart inside the given Node
class ChartAddEvent(val builder: Node.() -> Unit) : FXEvent()

class MainView : View() {
    override val root = borderpane {
        setPrefSize(1000.0, 750.0)
        paddingAll = 10
        top = hbox(5) {
            // Call the addChart function
            button("Show").action(::addChart)
        }
        center = vbox {
            subscribe<ChartAddEvent> { event ->
                // Remove existing children
                clear()

                // Call the builder inside the event with the vbox as it's parent
                event.builder(this@vbox)
            }
        }
    }

    // Fire a ChartAddEvent with a builder that will construct the chart 
    // inside a node designated by the event subscriber
    private fun addChart() {
        fire(ChartAddEvent {
            val seriesData = (1..25)
                    .map { Random().nextDouble() }
                    .zip((1..25).map { Random().nextDouble() })
                    .toMap()

            linechart("My Chart", NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()) {
                series("my series") {
                    for ((k, v) in seriesData) {
                        data(k, v)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```